# Display the full Datetime

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

I have to display the grid date as a datetime ex: 07-August-2012 09:30:00 with the full date and time. Every-time I use the formatter `d-M-y h:m:ss` I get junk values. Please help, I am working on creating a jqGrid in IBM BPM7.5 and the srcformat is `d/m/yyyy`.

Answer (score 1):

To format a date as `07-August-2012 09:30:00` you should be able to use:

```
d-F-Y H:i:s
```

According to the [jqGrid documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3apredefined_formatter), they use PHP date formatters:

> The definition of the date format uses the PHP conversions

So you can see [PHP: date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for an enumeration of the supported date/time formatting options.

Does that help?